# Кот ученый

Tags: литература, фразеология

Почему кот "ученый"? (И днем и ночью кот ученый все ходит по цепи кругом.)

Comment: Я  думаю,  что  в  сказке  кот  учёный  ничем  не  отличается  от  человека  учёного.  Разве  что... хвостом !

Comment: Первое  и  второе  предложения - вопросительные. Извините, недоглядел.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, тут значение самодостаточно. Ученый = дрессированный. Типичным было использование в "ученая собака" (пес) и особенно - "ученый медведь".
Только не надо путать с субстантивированным прилагательным ("товарищи ученые, доценты с кандидатами"). Это, кстати, даже великий лингвист Задорнов отметил в истории про "хатуль мадана".

~~~~
Вот из нацкорпуса только на "ученого медведя" (обратите внимение на контекст и даты)

1.Ю. П. Герман. Россия молодая. Часть первая (1952)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1) Даже ученого медведя не надо всегда бить. [Ю. П. Герман. Россия молодая. Часть первая (1952)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

2.В. М. Дорошевич. Сказки и легенды (1893-1916)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1) Ели плов, пили кофе, лакомились фруктами и рахат-лукумом, слушали музыку и смотрели на ученого медведя. [В. М. Дорошевич. Сказки и легенды (1893-1916)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

3.В. В. Верещагин. Наполеон I в России в картинах В. В. Верещагина (1899)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1) Из Вознесенского монастыря взяли священническую ризу и брачный венец, надели их на ученого медведя и заставили его плясать… [В. В. Верещагин. Наполеон I в России в картинах В. В. Верещагина (1899)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

4.В. В. Крестовский. Петербургские трущобы. Книга о сытых и голодных. Роман в шести частях. Ч. 4 (1864)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1) И вот, по требованию своей публики, Иван Родивоныч появляется на эстраде и отвешивает низкий поклон с грацией ученого медведя. [В. В. Крестовский. Петербургские трущобы. Книга о сытых и голодных. Роман в шести частях. Ч. 4 (1864)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

5.М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Губернские очерки (1856-1857)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1) Он показывает почтеннейшей публике главу «приятного семейства», как вожак показывает ученого медведя. [М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Губернские очерки (1856-1857)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

Comment: Думаю, это не единственно возможное объяснение. Надо подождать, что скажут учителя-филологи, — произведение-то программное, наверняка, такой вопрос возникал.

Comment: Здесь есть ученые-филологи? А кто? Нет, я не против послушать, наоборот, просто знать бы... 
У меня, к несчастью, погиб словарь языка Пушкина, если у кого под рукой, посмотрите, почти наверняка там разъяснено. 

Но большинство подобных вопросов где-то когда-то обсуждалось, другое дело, что я, разумеется, мог не о всех таких обсуждениях быть в курсе. Но этот вопрос помню.

Comment: УЧИТЕЛЯ-филологи. Здесь есть.

Comment: Словарь Пушкина под рукой - онлайн. Форматировать комментарий и вставлять ссылки не умею.Как-то уже спрашивала, но поняла только, что надо с клавиатуры вводить. А как?

Comment: Надо имитировать тот же текст, который вставляется в ответ по кнопке.
Введите ссылку обычным кописпастом, я разберусь, и с вашего позволения оформлю "красиво".

Впрочем не надо, я нашел.

1. Выученный, наученный чему-н. (3). У лукоморья дуб зеленый; Златая цепь на дубе том: И днем и ночью кот уче'ный Всё ходит по цепи кругом; РЛ I 3. Брадатый староста Авдей С поклоном барыне своей Заместо красного яичка Поднес уче'ного скворца. С3 89.4. 2.

[Тут][1]

[1]: http://slovari.ru/search.aspx?s=0&p=3068

Answer (score 2):

Воспринимается слово "ученый" в своем прямом значении ,поэтому дети вопросов не задают.  Я согласна с предыдущим ответом. Но синоним "дрессированный" мне не очень нравится, сразу вспоминаются   цирковые животных, выполняющих определенные действия по указу дрессировщика. Кот ученый - именно ученый. т.е. наученный.  Детям  можно рассказать и о связи пушкинского кота с фольклорным котом из русских сказок - котом Баюном, который, сидя  на высоком железном столбе, своими сказками   и заклинаниями лишает силы всех, кто хочет подойти к нему. А покоренный Иваном Царевичем, сказками исцеляет царя.

Comment: Не касаюсь того, что и как надо объяснять детям, но если отталкиваться от языка Пушкина, то "дессированный" тогда ещё просто не вошло в язык, зверюшек называли именно учеными. Возможно позднее "дессировка" и приобрела негативный оттенок, но я в ней вижу именно современный синоним "учености" нащих меньщих братьев.

Answer (score 1):

Оборот **кот-учёный** воспринимается как нечто редкое, что в общем неудивительно, поскольку коты действительно очень плохо поддаются дрессировке в отличие от собак. Отсюда, я думаю, и выражение кот-учёный, что обозначает как нечто редкое, невиданное.

Answer (score 0):

Откуда  известно, что  и  до  Пушкина  " кот  учёный" - оборот. Есть  примеры, что  так  называли  кого-нибудь,  чтобы  подчеркнуть  редкостность  этого  существа.  Кот  учёный  это  сказочный  персонаж. Он  же  ещё  и  сказки  рассказывает  и  песни  поёт. О  какой  дрессировке  речь?  А  то,  что  он  кот,  а  не  пёс  -  так  ведь  любит  котов  народ!